# Puzzled by RavenDB 'Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException'

Tags: c#, wpf, json, ravendb

I initialize my RavenDB DocumentStore like this:

```
void InitializeDocumentStore( string address )
{
    _documentStore = new DocumentStore()
    {
        Conventions =
        {
            FindTypeTagName = type =>
            {
                if ( typeof( IUser ).IsAssignableFrom( type ) )
                    return "IUser";
                return DocumentConvention.DefaultTypeTagName( type );
            }
        }
    };
    _documentStore.ParseConnectionString( "Url = " + address );
    _documentStore.Initialize();

    LoadStore();
}
```

And load documents like this:

```
void LoadStore()
{
    using (var session = _documentStore.OpenSession("storename"))
    {
        var userResult = from user in session.Query<IUser>()
                            where user.BaseType == typeof(IUser).Name
                            select user;

        foreach (var entry in userResult)
        {
            users.AddOrUpdate(entry.Id, entry, (key, oldValue) => entry != null ? entry : null);
        }
    }
}
```

This has worked fine for many week until I today cleaned my project (because of XAML) and now I receive this exception when attempting to loop through the userResults:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Raven.Abstractions.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Raven.Abstractions.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>SmartWard.Whiteboard.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException, Raven.Abstractions, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=37f41c7f99471593</ExceptionType><Message>Could not create an instance of type ABC.Model.Users.IUser. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantated. Path 'RoomNumber'.</Message><StackTrace>   at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean&amp;amp; createdFromNonDefaultConstructor) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 1275
   at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 353
   at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 229
   at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 155
   at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line 546
   at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line 512
   at Raven.Client.Connection.DocumentConventionJsonExtensions.Deserialize[T](RavenJObject self, DocumentConvention convention) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\DocumentConventionJsonExtensions.cs:line 22
   at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.ConvertToEntity[T](String id, RavenJObject documentFound, RavenJObject metadata) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:line 450
   at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity[T](String key, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:line 368
   at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Deserialize[T](RavenJObject result) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:line 153
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Complete[T]() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:line 135
   at Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.GetEnumerator() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\AbstractDocumentQuery.cs:line 753
   at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryInspector`1.GetEnumerator() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryInspector.cs:line 100
   at ABC.Infrastructure.ActivityBase.ActivitySystem.LoadStore() in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\ABC\ABC\ABC.Infrastructure\ActivityBase\ActivitySystem.cs:line 246
   at ABC.Infrastructure.ActivityBase.ActivitySystem.InitializeDocumentStore(String address) in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\ABC\ABC\ABC.Infrastructure\ActivityBase\ActivitySystem.cs:line 104
   at ABC.Infrastructure.ActivityBase.ActivitySystem.Run(String storeAddress) in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\ABC\ABC\ABC.Infrastructure\ActivityBase\ActivitySystem.cs:line 308
   at SmartWard.Infrastructure.WardNode.StartClientAndSystem() in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\SmartWard\SmartWard\Infrastructure\WardNode.cs:line 263
   at SmartWard.Infrastructure.WardNode.StartNode() in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\SmartWard\SmartWard\Infrastructure\WardNode.cs:line 228
   at SmartWard.Infrastructure.WardNode..ctor(WardNodeConfiguration configuration, WebConfiguration webConfiguration) in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\SmartWard\SmartWard\Infrastructure\WardNode.cs:line 221
   at SmartWard.Infrastructure.WardNode.StartWardNodeAsSystem(WebConfiguration webConfiguration) in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\SmartWard\SmartWard\Infrastructure\WardNode.cs:line 211
   at SmartWard.Whiteboard.ViewModels.BoardViewModel..ctor() in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\SmartWard\SmartWard.Whiteboard\ViewModels\BoardViewModel.cs:line 77
   at SmartWard.Whiteboard.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\SmartWard\SmartWard.Whiteboard\App.xaml.cs:line 16
   at System.Windows.Application.&amp;lt;.ctor&amp;gt;b__1(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at SmartWard.Whiteboard.App.Main() in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\SmartWard\SmartWard.Whiteboard\obj\Release\App.g.cs:line 50
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not create an instance of type ABC.Model.Users.IUser. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantated. Path 'RoomNumber'.
   at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean&amp;amp; createdFromNonDefaultConstructor) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 1275
   at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 353
   at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 229
   at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 155
   at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line 546
   at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line 512
   at Raven.Client.Connection.DocumentConventionJsonExtensions.Deserialize[T](RavenJObject self, DocumentConvention convention) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\DocumentConventionJsonExtensions.cs:line 22
   at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.ConvertToEntity[T](String id, RavenJObject documentFound, RavenJObject metadata) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:line 450
   at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity[T](String key, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:line 368
   at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Deserialize[T](RavenJObject result) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:line 153
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Complete[T]() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:line 135
   at Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.GetEnumerator() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\AbstractDocumentQuery.cs:line 753
   at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryInspector`1.GetEnumerator() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryInspector.cs:line 100
   at ABC.Infrastructure.ActivityBase.ActivitySystem.LoadStore() in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\ABC\ABC\ABC.Infrastructure\ActivityBase\ActivitySystem.cs:line 246
   at ABC.Infrastructure.ActivityBase.ActivitySystem.InitializeDocumentStore(String address) in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\ABC\ABC\ABC.Infrastructure\ActivityBase\ActivitySystem.cs:line 104
   at ABC.Infrastructure.ActivityBase.ActivitySystem.Run(String storeAddress) in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\ABC\ABC\ABC.Infrastructure\ActivityBase\ActivitySystem.cs:line 308
   at SmartWard.Infrastructure.WardNode.StartClientAndSystem() in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\SmartWard\SmartWard\Infrastructure\WardNode.cs:line 263
   at SmartWard.Infrastructure.WardNode.StartNode() in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\SmartWard\SmartWard\Infrastructure\WardNode.cs:line 228
   at SmartWard.Infrastructure.WardNode..ctor(WardNodeConfiguration configuration, WebConfiguration webConfiguration) in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\SmartWard\SmartWard\Infrastructure\WardNode.cs:line 221
   at SmartWard.Infrastructure.WardNode.StartWardNodeAsSystem(WebConfiguration webConfiguration) in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\SmartWard\SmartWard\Infrastructure\WardNode.cs:line 211
   at SmartWard.Whiteboard.ViewModels.BoardViewModel..ctor() in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\SmartWard\SmartWard.Whiteboard\ViewModels\BoardViewModel.cs:line 77
   at SmartWard.Whiteboard.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\SmartWard\SmartWard.Whiteboard\App.xaml.cs:line 16
   at System.Windows.Application.&amp;lt;.ctor&amp;gt;b__1(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at SmartWard.Whiteboard.App.Main() in c:\Users\Pitlab\Documents\GitHub\SmartWard\SmartWard.Whiteboard\obj\Release\App.g.cs:line 50
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</ExceptionString><DataItems><Data></Data></DataItems></Exception></TraceRecord>
```

I am completely puzzled why EXACTLY the same code stops working after a clean and I have no idea where to begin debugging this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the TraceRecord (line 4); it contains the specific serializer exception:

```
<Message>Could not create an instance of type ABC.Model.Users.IUser. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantated. Path 'RoomNumber'.</Message><StackTrace>
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't understand why this exception is thrown. The code was written weeks ago and work fine until I cleaned the solution.

Comment: Do you use source control? Can you see if perhaps anyone else changed something seemingly innocuous that could be affecting this?

Comment: Yes, I have source control but I have not made any changes to the failing codebase (and I don't push libs/exe). I was working on the UI, which is a separate project. I removed the WPF projects and tested the code using nothing but a console app, and the same error occurs. It is as if, there is a library missing, but I don't get any reference errors or anything else

Comment: You were right. Because I moved the model to another namespace during refactoring, RavenDB could not map them and hence only used the IUser interface which obviously cannot be instantiated. Thanks for the lead.